# Write failed, errno 0

Tags: c, networking, linux-kernel

I have a client server situation in which I receive data using

```
read(socket, char_buf, BUF_SIZE)
```

and then try to write it into a log file using

```
write(filefd, char_buf, strlen(char_buf))
```

Strangely enough this fails (write returns -1), and yet the errno is set to 0, and I can print the message, AND the log file descriptor works (I write to it before and after this command).

What's going on??

(Working on Linux kernel 2.4 (homework))

Comment: Make sure some library call (used by error handling) doesn't override the errno. Try running the program under strace.

Comment: What does read() return? Does it work as you expect?  What do you see when you do something like `fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));`?

Comment: I'm fairly certain read() does not work on sockets, only files, but that would not affect the write.  Can you show code which shows you handling the error?

Comment: read() should work on sockets, but it won't let you pass in flags or get the sender's address (for datagrams).

Comment: @vput3833 It says Bad File Descriptor. I guess that solves it. Although I have no idea what may have caused the errno to be zero. I'm running the server program on the same machine, and it uses pthreads. Can that somehow mess up the errno?

Comment: @Dummy00001 I didn't see anything out of the ordinary...

Comment: @vput3833. Can you post an answer with your suggestion of using strerror. This showed me there is a problem with the descriptor so I'd like to vote it up and accept it as the answer.

Comment: 'errno' in glibc actually refers to a per-thread variable.  If you're feeling adventurous, look at the assembly instructions generated for an errno reference some time.

Comment: OP was using Linux 2.4, and thus must have also been using the completely-buggy-and-nonconformant LinuxThreads rather than NPTL, so it's likely that something went wrong with includes and/or linking that caused the wrong `errno` to be read or written...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int reads = read(socket, char_buf, BUF_SIZE);

if ( reads != BUF_SIZE )
{
    /* something might have gone wrong */
    fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", strerror( errno ));
}

int writes= = write( filedes, buffer, buffer_size );

if ( writes != buffer_size )
{
    /* something might have gone wrong */
    fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", strerror( errno ));
}
```

I'd do something like this always following a read or write or such calls.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the status of your read()?  It may have an error, that results in the length of char_buf to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Step through your code with a debugger and make sure that each statement is doing exactly what you think it should be doing.  I bet you'll find an earlier bug.

Also, the return value for the `read()` is important.  It tells you how many bytes were actually read.  For a successful read, it could be anywhere between 1 and `BUF_SIZE`.